# ui.bootstrap.modal: how to open cloned item recursively

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui.bootstrap

I'm looking for a way to open modal window with a new context within already opened modal. How should I modify openItemModal() in order to open cloned item?

```
function openItemModal() {
                    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                        animation: true,
                        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
                        controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, item) {

                                $scope.item = item;

                                $scope.clone = function () {
                                    var clonedItem = angular.copy($scope.item);

                                    $scope.item = clonedItem;
                                    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                                    openItemModal();

                                };
                            },
                            resolve: {
                                item: function () {
                                    return $scope.item;
                                }
                            }
                        });
        }
```

Edit:
`openItemModal()` calling when clicking on Item

Edit 2: The best decision I could find was copying `openItemModal()` method with adding ability to pass items. Thus, I called `openClonedItemModal(clonedItem)`, which solved the problem.

Comment: Maybe it will be simpler to use the Promise of `modalInstance.result` to call `openItemModal()` again

Comment: I've tried (without success). Assigning $scope.item to clonedItem doesn't work